# Calculate the sum of a column if another cell contains Y in the resulted column

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/7c5b8d7a6de2e2642e3476ab8f3d01cf.png]

I want to sum the entire Profit column but only if the neighbouring Resulted cell is marked Y, I also need the rows to be extensible so use F:F instead of F1:F12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Sumifs() function or the Sumif() function. I prefer Sumifs because it can easily be extended to contain more conditions and because the sum range is always the first parameter.

```
=sumifs(F:F,G:G,"Y")
```

So, add up F if G is Y.

If you turn your data into an Excel Table object (using Insert > Table or Ctrl-T) you can use the structured reference for the column header instead of the whole column reference for the workbook. Assuming the table is called Table1:

```
=Sumifs(Table1[Profit],Table1[Resulted],"Y")
```

Sumif is a bit less intuitive, because if the values you want to sum are not in the column that you check for the condition, then the column to sum goes in the third parameter.

```
=sumif(G:G,"Y",F:F)
```

If G is "Y" sum F.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please mark the answer as explained in the [Tour]. That's how you can say "thanks" around here.